# Is advancement in Demon Hunters one or two pyramids?

Tags: character-advancement, demon-hunters-rpg

While Demon Hunters is based on Fate Core and FAE, it differs from both in that there are Approaches and Disciplines, one of each apply to every check. Each Approach and Discipline is assigned one of d4–d12. During advancement, you can step up these dice — within certain limits.

> When you step up an approach or discipline, there’s a pyramid-shaped cap
>   you must always adhere to. It works like this:
>
> - You can’t have more than one approach at d12 or discipline at d12.
> - You can’t have more than two approaches at d10 or disciplines at d10.
> - You can’t have more than three approaches at d8 or disciplines at d8.

I don't quite understand the wording: can I have *both* an Approach *and* a Discipline at d12 (two pyramics), or can I only have one d12 in total (one pyramid)?

Given that characters start with a d10, 2d8, 2d6, d4 spread in Approaches and d10, d8, d6, 2-3d4 in Disciplines, the latter interpretation would not give them very freedom, so I'm *guessing* it's supposed to be two pyramids. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cam Banks, one of the designers of the game, [says](https://www.facebook.com/groups/brotherhoodofthecelestialtorch/permalink/1181797398551599/?comment_id=1184363508294988):

> The intent was there's a separate pyramid of each of the two kinds of stats. Your dice in approaches and in disciplines are completely independent of each other.